# Can functions be local in Julia and what does that imply?

Tags: function, julia

According to the Julia repl using Julia 1.1, this is valid Julia:

```
julia> local function f()
       5
       end
(::getfield(Main, Symbol("#f#8"))) (generic function with 1 method)
```

What does having a local function in say a module mean? Is it private is it public? Are not all functions declared local by default for the scope that they are declared in? And if that is the case the local keyword is redundant for functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does having local function in say a module mean?

I think this syntax should be disallowed. It is not documented what it does. I have opened a discussion [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/usage-of-local-keyword-in-global-scope/25325) to clarify this issue.

> Is it private is it public?

This syntax - as far as I can tell - defines a function that is not introduced into a global methods table of the module. Therefore effectively this definition is similar to defining an anonymous function, so you can do something like this:

```
julia> x = (local f() = 1)
(::getfield(Main, Symbol("#f#3"))) (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x()
1
```

> Are not all functions declared local by default for the scope that they are declared in?

Yes. You are not allowed to add a method to a global method table from a local scope. The only way to do it is by using `eval` which is in general not recommended in normal code.

> And if that is the case the local keyword is redundant for functions?

No, it is not fully redundant, as sometimes it is needed in nested local scopes (as in general `local` is needed in local scopes for any variable name). See this example:

```
julia> function f1()
           f2() = 10
           for i in 1:2
               f2() = i
               println(f2())
           end
       end
f1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f1()
ERROR: UndefVarError: i not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] f1() at .\REPL[3]:2
 [2] top-level scope at none:0

julia> function f1()
           f2() = 10
           for i in 1:2
               local f2() = i
               println(f2())
           end
       end
f1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f1()
1
2
```

**EDIT**

As noted on Discourse here is an explanation of this issue https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/10472#issuecomment-321584501 on GitHub.

In summary - it works as I have assumed, and the technical reason is that if Julia sees `local` keyword in global scope an implicit local scope is created so values can leak out of this scope but not variable bindings.